# Unable to access textbox and button on specific website using Selenium WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm taking my first steps in selenium, and am facing a strange problem right now. I want to navigate on a website and enter text in a search box as well as click the "enter"-button to proceed to the next page. In general, I know how to do this, and it works seamlessly on other websites, but this one seems to cause trouble somehow. When I search the textbox and button by name, it just can't find them. Same problem if I try to access them via xPath or ID... 
The website is: http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/ (Database of German Swimming Association)

My code so far looks like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("_submitButton")
fistname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_firstnameTextBox"]')
lastname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_lastnameTextBox"]')
regid_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("_regidTextBox")

fistname_textbox.send_Keys("String 1")
lastname_textbox.send_keys("String 2")
submit_button.click()

driver.close()
```

If any of you could help me and find out what causes this problem, I would be super grateful :) I'm getting more and more confused right now

Answer (score 0):

The all section is inside `<iframe>` tag, you need to switch to it first

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("_submitButton")
#...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I get an Error message: wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @juliu_mbr Try `wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))` with double `(())`

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts to locate the element are unsuccessful because of they are nested within an `iframe`. One must tell selenium to switch to the `iframe` that contains the desired element before attempting to click it or use it in any way. Try the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(0);
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("_submitButton")
fistname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_firstnameTextBox"]')
lastname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_lastnameTextBox"]')
regid_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("_regidTextBox")

fistname_textbox.send_keys("String 1")
lastname_textbox.send_keys("String 2")
submit_button.click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The *textbox and button* elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/")
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@src='https://dsvdaten.dsv.de/Modules/Results/Individual.aspx?Lang=de-DE']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='TextBox' and @id='_firstnameTextBox']"))).send_keys("juliu_mbr")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='TextBox' and @id='_lastnameTextBox']").send_keys("juliu_mbr")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='Button' and @id='_submitButton']").click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: dsv_de]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to frame and then locate the elements

```
url = "http://www.dsv.de/schwimmen/wettkampf-national/schwimmerabfrage/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src='https://dsvdaten.dsv.de/Modules/Results/Individual.aspx?Lang=de-DE']'));

// then your code for the Login

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("_submitButton")
fistname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_firstnameTextBox"]')
lastname_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_lastnameTextBox"]')
regid_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("_regidTextBox")

fistname_textbox.send_Keys("String 1")
lastname_textbox.send_keys("String 2")
submit_button.click()

driver.close()
```